# aws_route_table_association doesn't work for all private* subnets - terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, devops, terraform

I have created couple of subnets using the resource block below.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count                   = "${length(var.private_subnet)}"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.private_subnet[count.index]}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.private}-${format("%01d", count.index + 1)}"
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

After which I created eip's, nat's, private route table, added route to the private route table and lastly, when I try to associate the private route table to private* subnets terraform works partially i.e. out of 4 subnets only 2 private subnets are associated with the private route table.

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-subnet-association" {
  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.private_route_table.id}"
}
```

What do I have to change to apply the association to all the private subnets.

```
subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.private*.?.id, count.index)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the variable `nat_gateway_eip` coming from? You need to reference  by the full resource in the format `TYPE.NAME.ATTR`

It should look something like this... `${element(aws_eip.RESOURCE_NAME.*.id, count.index)}`

Or you need to have whatever module/file that is creating the `nat_gateway` output the `eip_id` value and reference it from remote state.

**Edit:** Updating answer as question has changed.

You need to create multiple associations to associate this route table to different subnets.

Your current subnet association block is not iterating anything. The syntax `RESOURCE.NAME.*.ATTR` doesn't mean "wildcard", it's for use with a resource containing a `count`.

Comment: nat_gateway_eip comes from variables.tf and dev.tfvars files.

I have modified the resource block and have added 

`subnet_id      = "${element(aws_eip.aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)}"` 

Here's the error:

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_route.private_route: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_route.private_route: Error creating route: InvalidNatGatewayID.NotFound: The natGateway ID 'eipalloc-02ee81ff53c730ac0' does not exist
        status code: 400, request id: 4692a51b-fbd4-4a02-a0d3-f4745b07bc6a

Comment: I removed the count for aws_nat_gateway. Now we'll only have 1 NAT Gateway vs 2 like before. 

But the issue of route table associating for all private / privatedb subnets still persists.

`#Associate subnet private_subnet to private route table 

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-subnet-association" {
  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.private_route_table.id}"
}`

After the resource block is executed only one private subnet route table association changes but the other one still remains same.